# Mousepad tap does not work on debian stable lxde

Tags: debian, touchpad, debian-wheezy, mouse-click, lxde

I have an Acer Aspire One KAV60 running debian 7.0 stable with lxde as the window manager.

I can't get the mousepad to register a click when I tap it.

I've tried installing gpointing-device-settings, which works for some settings like using 2 fingers to scroll, but does nothing when I turn mousepad taps on or off.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: It's strange that this question has been viewed 35 times but no one has even commented on what the problem may be. Please help! :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Building on responses from Larry and user193782, I found that this worked for LXDE on Debian stable (wheezy):

```
$ su
$ cd /etc/X11/Xsession.d
$ vi 99-synclient
```

The file 99-synclient should contain:

```
#! /bin/sh
synclient TapButton1=1
```

Then make the 99-synclient executable:

```
$ chmod 555 99-synclient
```

Answer (score 5):

I had exactly the same problem with a fresh install of Wheezy on my Asus eee 901GO - I googled the problem and the answer was the next page listed after this! It's quite simple by all accounts - as superuser (at least I was) type the following command in a terminal:

```
synclient TapButton1=1
```

Worked first time for me.

Comment: On LXDE, debian stable (wheezy), this only works after it has been typed into a terminal. To make it happen automatically, see my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Please try these steps:

1. Open Root Terminal(Menu>Accessories>Root Terminal)
2. Enter the Administrative password
3. Type the following commands:

   ```
   mkdir /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d
   leafpad /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/synaptics.conf
   ```
4. Copy the following script

   ```
   Section "InputClass"
   Identifier      "Touchpad"
   MatchIsTouchpad "yes"  
   Driver          "synaptics"                     
   Option          "MinSpeed"              "0.5"
   Option          "MaxSpeed"              "1.0"
   Option          "AccelFactor"           "0.075"
   Option          "TapButton1"            "1"
   Option          "TapButton2"            "2"    
   Option          "TapButton3"            "3"     
   Option          "VertTwoFingerScroll"   "1"     
   Option          "HorizTwoFingerScroll"  "1"     
   Option          "VertEdgeScroll"        "1"
   Option          "CoastingSpeed"         "8"
   Option          "CornerCoasting"        "1"
   Option          "CircularScrolling"     "1"
   Option          "CircScrollTrigger"     "7"
   Option          "EdgeMotionUseAlways"   "1"
   Option          "LBCornerButton"        "8"   
   Option          "RBCornerButton"        "9"     
   EndSection
   ```
5. Then paste it to the synaptics.conf file
6. Click File and Save
7. Logoff and login again.....

Answer (score 0):

Same issue here with wheezy and GNOME 3! synclient works for the current session and none of the advise I found in the net worked for me to make it permanent.

Here's how I finally did it:

dconf-editor, under `org/gnome/settings-daemon/peripherals/touchpad` there's a tap-to-click checkbox.

Wish this helps.